# Compare two drop down list values, if a selection is made in one but not the other an error is thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two drop down lists. I need a selection made in the second one if there is a selection in the first one.

```
if((ddl1.SelectedIndex > -1 ) != (ddl2.SelectedIndex > -1))
{
    this.lblError.Visible = true;
}
```

So basically if the there is a selection in the first one but not the second one then error.

Would it be the drop down it's self??

```
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRate1" runat="server">
                   <asp:ListItem Value="">(Select)</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>Initial</asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem>Moderate</asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: you realize that is not the same ID as in the c# if statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED from your comments , UPDATED AGAIN..

this is why I originally wrote it with 2 if statements,

```
if((ddl1.SelectedIndex > 0  ) {   

     //code to read value from ddl1

             if (ddl2.SelectedIndex == 0))
            {
                this.lblError.Visible = true;
                // or maybe a bool 'IsValid'  maybe..
            }
}
```

Then assuming you have code like this throughout your form , at the end you could do

```
if ( this.lblError.Visible == true) {  // code to handle invalid form }
```

OR..

```
if ((ddl1.SelectedIndex > 0 )  && (ddl2.SelectedIndex == 0)) {
     this.lblError.Visible = true;
}
```

Try this for trouble shooting - before the if statement

```
 this.lblError.Visible = true;
 this.lblError.Text = "ddl1 : " + ddl1.SelectedIndex.ToString() + " ddl2 : " + ddl2.SelectedIndex.ToString();
```

Comment: How about using `&&` instead?

Comment: This doesn't work could the drop down it's self be the problem?

Comment: Well the error error label does not become visible and it just moves to the next method call. Sorry don't mean to be vague. It just run as if the if statement wasn't there.

Comment: @briskovich are you debugging using IE?

Comment: this is what I got. ddl1 : 2 ddl2 : 0  So ddl2 should be on -1 and ddl1 should begin on -1

Comment: @ScottSelby - my selected index begins on 0

Comment: @ScottSelby - thanks for helping me by the way. That works as expected but now when no selection is made then. Do I need to do a else if to account for the ddl=0 && ddl2 = 0 ??

Comment: This code was appearently for validation purposes , the other code you are talking about would be in the code that reads the value

Comment: Yes this was just for validation. The thing is that the user may not enter a value in any of the drop downs. But if they do in that one then they have to enter one in the second one.

Comment: That revision will not work in this situation. I am accepting the answer though. Thank you so much for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
if((ddl1.SelectedIndex > -1 ) && !(ddl2.SelectedIndex > -1))
{
    this.lblError.Visible = true;
}
```

This is pretty much just a translation of what you've said, "is a selection in the first one but not the second one"  Where the first one has a value (is greater than -1) **and** where the second one does **not** have a value.

You could refactor this in several ways, such as by using `ddl2.SelectedIndex == -1` for the second value, but this code reads exactly like you've described how it should work, and there really isn't anything *wrong* with it, so that is worth a lot in my eyes.

Comment: This doesn't work. I doesn't seem to evaluate the second box. could it be the dropdown its self?

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work".  What is happening that shouldn't, or what isn't happening that should?

Comment: Well the error error label does not become visible and it just moves to the next method call.

Comment: @briskovich And what is the selected index of each drop down list at the time?  Also, where are you calling the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server">
               <asp:ListItem Value="">(Select)</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="Initial">Initial</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="Moderate">Moderate</asp:ListItem>
                 </asp:DropDownList>
```

C#

```
if((ddl1.SelectedValue.Length > 0 ) && (ddl2.SelectedValue.Length == 0))
{
    this.lblError.Visible = true;
}
```